# .emacs location

Tags: microsoft-windows, configuration-files

I am trying to locate .emacs file . I have installed emacs auctex from a zip file obtained from ctan.org on windows 7. 
I tried to search.emacs within directory but nothing returned. 
Kindly help

Comment: If it doesn't already exist, then create it in the proper location -- it is a flat text file.  See:  **Where can I find my .emacs file for Emacs running on Windows?**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows and **Where do I put my init file?**:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Location-of-init-file.html and **Emacs Wiki -- MsWindowsDotEmacs**:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MsWindowsDotEmacs

Comment: Note that most people will advise users to install AUCTeX through the package manager:  `M-x list-packages`  There are also pre-built binaries that have AUCTeX already installed; e.g., Vincent Goulet:  https://vigou3.github.io/emacs-modified-windows/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10545955 may also help.

Comment: I think the answer is the same for Windows 7 and 8.1, making these questions dupes? I think the answer on the linked question applies here.